# Compiler was unable to honor this factoryMethod customization

Tags: jaxb, jaxb2, xjc

I need to use "factoryMethod" to resolve "Two declarations cause a collision in the ObjectFactory class.". However, I receive "Compiler was unable to honor this factoryMethod customization". I could find no info about "factoryMethod". It seems I'm not using it right. Please look at my simplified schema:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" jxb:version="2.1">
    <xs:element name="UseCase">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="StepAction" >
                    <xs:annotation>
                        <xs:appinfo>
                            <jxb:factoryMethod name="createStepAction" />
                        </xs:appinfo>
                    </xs:annotation>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

I use "xjc %schemaname%" to produce classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that jxb:factoryMethod can be used only for elements xjc complains about. In my example, I had to cause "Compiler was unable to honor this factoryMethod customization" by adding other element at the same level as StepAction:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" jxb:version="2.1">
    <xs:element name="UseCase">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="StepAction" >
                    <xs:annotation>
                        <xs:appinfo>
                            <jxb:factoryMethod name="createStepAction" />
                        </xs:appinfo>
                    </xs:annotation>
                </xs:element>

                <xs:element name="Step-Action"/> <!-- causes Compiler was unable to honor this factoryMethod customization -->

            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

XJC doesn't throw "Compiler was unable to honor this factoryMethod customization" in this case.

My conclusions:

- One cannot use jxb:factoryMethod to change a name of ObjectFactory's createXXX method if XJC doesn't produce "Two declarations cause a collision in the ObjectFactory class." error
- "Two declarations cause a collision in the ObjectFactory class." is produced when there are more than one element with conflicting names at the same level (siblings). If they are at different level, xjc won't complain. By conflicting names I mean names which are the same after XJC's tranformation (e.g. "Step-Action" and "StepAction" are the same)
- jxb:class annotation has no effect on ObjectFactory's createXXX methods